# Meaning of "Past seventy they are now."

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Listening in the hall, Lucy heard her mama suggest that maybe they
> should go, that maybe they had no choice. She didn’t understand what was
> meant by that, or what it was that would quieten. She moved closer to the
> slightly open door because the voices were lower than they had been.
>
> -We have to think of her, Everard.
>
> -I know.
>
> And in the kitchen Bridget said:
>
> -The Morells have gone from Clashmore.
>
> "I heard." Henry’s slow enunciation reached Lucy in the dog passage,
> which was what the passage that led from the kitchen to the back door was
> called. "I heard that all right."
>
> **"Past seventy they are now."**
>
> Henry said nothing for a moment, then remarked that at times like these
> the worst was always assumed, the benefit of any doubt going the wrong
> way in any misfortune there’d be. The Gouvernets had gone from Aglish,
> he said, the Priors from Ringville, the Swifts, the Boyces. Everywhere,
> what you heard about was the going.

**Does it mean: they are now more than seventy?**

**I think "they" refer to Morells**

Source: The Story of Lucy Gault by William trevor

Comment: It means they are past the age of seventy.

Answer (score 1):

> Past seventy they are now.

This has the same meaning as the more typical order:

> They are now past seventy.

“past” for ages means “older than”. We sometimes look at age (or time generally) as a metaphorical distance that people travel, and to say someone has passed a certain age means they are now older than that age.

Comment: Alternatively,  it might mean that a group has more than seventy members. Its hard to tell from the context given.

Comment: @StephenS, so you mean: They are older than seventy? but I think they are a group and beacuse of that I think "past" here means "more than". is it ever correct to say: past=more than.